# draw arc using start, end and initial direction

Tags: math, geometry

I am trying to draw a railway in the way it is implemented in railroad tycoon 3. I have understood some of the patterns by which this is done, but I cannot find a formula for their application. I am trying to build an arc using only two points and some initial direction. For simplicity, let's assume that I can only plot a path in the range from 0 to 90 degrees. The arc should always start in the direction of "Initial direction". I need a method that would implement this. I tried to depict the idea in the drawings. Any pseudocode would do I guess.

[general idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7JkW.png)

[borderline case at alpha = 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAHNP.png)

[borderline case at alpha = 90 degrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDTK2.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Center `C` lies at middle perpendicular to `SE` segment, so we should find vectors

```
se = (E.x - S.x, E.y - S.y)
perp = (-se.y, se.x) = (S.y - E.y, E.x - S.x)    //MC direction
```

and middle point

```
M = ((E.x + S.x)/2, (E.y - S.y)/2)
```

and express `C` coordinates using parametric equation

```
C = M + perp*t
```

Note that initial arc direction `d` is perpendicular to radius `CS`, so their dot product is zero:

```
(C - S).dot.d = 0

(M.x + perp.x * t - S.x)*d.x + (M.y + perp.y * t - S.y)*d.y = 0
```

This is linear equation for unknown parameter `t`, after solving it we know center `C` and can build the arc.

[image]

Python code. Perhaps examples are too simple to reveal bugs, but the first with half-circle gives R=L/2, center at M, and the second one shows correct C position and R.

```
from math import hypot, atan2
def arcfromptsdir(sx, sy, ex, ey, dx, dy):
    sex = ex - sx
    sey = ey - sy
    perpx = -sey
    perpy = sex
    mx = (ex + sx) / 2
    my = (ey + sy) / 2
    #equation
    #(sex/2 + perpx * t )*dx + (sey/2 + perp.y * t )*dy = 0
    p = perpx * dx + perpy * dy
    if p:
        t = -0.5*(sex*dx + sey*dx) / p
    else:
        return None
    #centerx, centery, radius
    cx = mx + perpx * t
    cy = my + perpy * t
    radius = hypot(cx-sx, cy-sy)
    arcangle = atan2((sx-cx) * (ey-cy) - (sy-cy) * (ex-cx), 
                     (sx-cx) * (ex-cx) + (sy-cy) * (ey-cy))
    return (cx, cy, radius, arcangle)

print(arcfromptsdir(0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1))
print(arcfromptsdir(0, 0, 2, 0, 0.7071, 0.7071))

(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -3.141592653589793)
(1.0, -1.0, 1.4142135623730951, -1.5707963267948966)
```

Comment: Thank you. I really think you're a genius. although it doesn't work exactly as I expected, I wanted the radius to be L/2 at 90 degrees. Do you happen to have any idea how to better control behavior? Maybe use a chord and get a radius from it? Wait I'll add video.

Comment: For 90 degrees `perp = -d*coeff`, and equation should give solution t=0, that leads to C==M and R=L/2

Comment: I added example implementation